# What are these connectors called?

Tags: connector, terminology

There are two horizontal connectors in this illustration, one with four pins  and one with six pins.

What are these connectors called?

[image: http://code.google.com/p/arducopter/wiki/AC2_Radio]

Comment: See also Molex KK series.

Comment: They aren't much use. They are only available in two rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called crimp housings. Harwin makes them:

http://www.harwin.com/M20-106/M20-1060400-product.html

and they are widely available. I get the 10-way ones and cut them down to the size I need.

Comment: If you buy crimp housings, don't forget to buy crimps too. And a crimp tool.

Answer (score 2):

They are generic "Rectangular Connectors" (....yeah). Digikey actually has a whole set of subgroups under the connector heading labeled "Rectangular":
[image]

Every manufacturer has their own line, with their own part number. However, searching for 0.100" (the spacing between pins) Rectangular connectors on a electronics component retailer's website should get you in the general area.

Answer (score 1):

They are header receptacles.  As pictured, they look like they could be constructed using header receptacle housings.  In this case each attached wire would have an individual crimped connection that is then inserted into the housing.